# Iterating dictionary and add column to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary consisting of several keys that have multiple values assigned to them:

```
dict ={
'key1':'val1(ex1)|val2',
'key2':'val3 (ex2)|val4',
'key3':'val5',
'key4':'val6|val7|val8|val9'
}
```

The single keys consist of values having different lengths, that means that the count of elements in a value expression separated by "|" differs for the keys.
Therefore, conversion to a dataframe is not possible as all arrays have to have the same length.

Then I have a dataframe in where one columns contains the values of the dictionary above.
So target is to iterate over all rows in the dataframe column, match the value with the dictionary values and enter the corresponding key to a new column in the dataframe.

So far I use the following loop:

```
for key, val in dict.items():
    df.loc[(df['Values'].str.contains(val)),'new_col'] = key
```

This seems to work partly already but sometimes (not always) values are not matched, especially if they contain parenthesis (like 'val1(example)' ).

End result should look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lIBr.png)

Would it be better to create a list of values in the dictionary?
How should it work as my first attempt got me an error saying list are not hashable?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Apparently the loop didn't work well with "str.contains(val)" part.
As the values that are assigned to keys are constant, I converted the values to a list like this:

```
'key1':['val1(ex1),val2'],
#and so on...
```

and changed the loop as follows:

```
for key, val in dict.items():
    for i in val:
        df.loc[(df['Values']== i),'new_col'] = key
```

This solved the problem.
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Some code showing the attempt you describe would likely be very helpful for our understanding. As it's written, it's not very clear what you are trying to do. Consider whipping up a minimal reproducible example so we can copy/paste and solve on our machines.

Comment: Invert your dictionary to `inverted = {'val1': 'key1', 'val2': 'key1', ...}`. Then use `df['col'].apply(inverted)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to define a dictionary by assigning to it the value of each base (for example val1) with respect to key where I applied the regular expressions to pull the base value out of strings in the df and I allowed the sort of functionality when encountering a string such as val1(example). So when I find that the base value is present in the dictionary of the reverse mapping, I will find corresponding key and output their results; otherwise it is a no match.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

my_dict = {
    'key1': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
    'key2': ['val4', 'val5'],
    'key3': ['val6'],
    'key4': ['val7', 'val8', 'val9']
}

# I created hete a reverse mapping
value_to_key = {v: k for k, vals in my_dict.items() for v in vals}

df = pd.DataFrame({'values': ['val1(example)', 'val4', 'val9', 'val3']})

# the func to clean and match values
def match_value(val):
    # Extracting the base value (assuming format 'value(something)')
    base_val = re.match(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', val).group(1)
    return value_to_key.get(base_val, 'No Match')

df['keys'] = df['values'].apply(match_value)

print(df)
```